# How can I move a Site Page to a sub-folder?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, sitepages, move

In our Office 365 SharePoint, (annoyingly) I can only add pages from "New" menu on the site home page.

When I add pages, they end up in the top level of the Pages area. I'd like to be able to move them to sub-folders to structure them, but when I select a page there is only the "Copy to" option (see image).

Does anyone know if there is configuration I'm missing to enable moves or anything I can add in to enable this?

A workaround is to use "Copy To" and then delete pages in the root but I don't want users to have to do this.

Thanks,

Chris.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Amending this path “/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx” at the end site collection URL.

Then you can move site pages:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that URL change gave me access to the classic (?) view. I don't see the Move... option in the menu here though. Am I missing a permission?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see a option of "Move To" you can simply Automate this stuff using PowerAutomate (refer image below). this Flow can be executed from the context menu ([3 dots] ...) you see in Site Pages

**NOTE** The below flow moves 1 file at a time only

[image]

Comment: But what's the trigger for that flow?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if the PowerAutomate is blocked from being associated with the site pages library therefore the Flow doesn't show up when the item is selected so there is no way to trigger in the usual way. I also tried to just grab the files (site pages) I wanted and apply the move to each one but Flow reports it can't find the library (obviously it is blocked). This doesn't work... Microsoft again wins in the battle to prevent users from being able to do what they want to do.